# Global maxima of $f(x,y)=x^2y$ restricted to D

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Let $f(x,y) = x^2y$ and $D = \{(x,y): y\geq0 \land 2x^2+y^2 \leq a\}$ with $a>0$.

I need to find $a$ such that the global maxima of $f$ restricted to $D$ is $\frac{1}{8}$.

I found, using Lagrange multipliers, that $a$ = $\frac{3}{4}$. With that value, $f(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) = f(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{8}$, and those points are *local* maxima.

Tha part where I am struggling with is to prove that those are *global* maxima.

The restriction now states that $2x^2+y^2 \leq \frac{3}{4}$, but from there I can't get a close enough bound for $x^2y$. What else can I try?

Thank you.

Comment: I suppose you meant $f(-0.5, 0.5) = 1/8$?

Comment: You're right. I edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is monotonic in $y$, so that by definition, for each constant $x$, the maximum will be found on the upper half of the ellipse's boundary.

Thus, you can search for local maxima of:
$$f(x,y) = x^2\sqrt{a-2x^2}$$ 
Which will then be global maxima of $f(x,y)$ on $D$, and also happen to coincide with the local minima you already found.

Comment: I don't understand. What does it mean that it is monotonic in $y$?

Comment: @Steve - Look at the function only as a function of $y$: the function is just a straight line, right? That means that it's maximum will always be on the boundary.

Comment: But, for example, what about $f(y,y)=y^3$?

Comment: I could see that the critical points where $f(x,y) = 1/8$ are on the border of the region. Is Lagrange proof enough that there aren't larger values inside?

Comment: @Steve - it's enough in general, but in this case it is. $f(y,y)$ is not a function - it's a constant value.

Answer (score 0):

i am wondering if you can do this. we need to find the maximum of $k$ so that $$y = \frac k{x^2} \tag 1$$ touches the ellipse $$2x^2 + y^2 = a \tag 2$$ in the first quadrant.

for $(1)$ an $(2)$ to touch, $$2x^2 + \frac{k^2}{x^4} = a $$ must have a double root. that is, with $x^2 = u$ the function $g(u) = 2u^3 - au^2 + k^2$  and its derivative $g'(u) = 6u^2 - 2au = 0$ must have a positive common root $u = a/3.$ so that 
$$0 = g(a/3) = \frac 2{27}a^3 - \frac 19a^3 + k^2 = 0 \to k = \left(\frac a 3\right)^{3/2} \text{ or } a = 3k^{2/3}$$ which agrees with the max pair found 
$a = \frac 34, k = \frac1 8.$

Comment: So that would confirm that they are absolute maxima because Lagrange didn't find other critical points inside the region?

Comment: it is the absolute maxima because there was only tangent point common to both.

Comment: Thank you for your help, abel.